# Keyboard shortcut to highlight the text in adobe reader

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

What is the keyboard shortcut to highlight the text in the adobe reader on Mac?

Do some settings in adobe reader preferences need to be changed to use it?

For some strange reason I am not able to access Adobe reader preferences. No window shows up when I use that option or use mac shortcut for that <kbd>cmd</kbd> +<kbd>,</kbd>